# Does Aptana support custom page templates?

Tags: aptana

I'm fairly new to using Aptana, but I'm wondering if it supports a feature that I used to use a lot in Dreamweaver, where you could create a page template, i.e. the header and footer of a page that would stay the same for each page on a website, leaving only the content to be coded.

I found this feature really useful as you only needed to change code once for it to propagate to all pages.

I've searched for this feature in Aptana, but I'm not sure on the exact terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently. There have been requests for it, but it has not yet been implemented:

https://aptana.lighthouseapp.com/projects/35272/tickets/2140-allow-for-dreamweaver-like-templates

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case, but it is good to know for sure.